# How to determine the process that controls/blocks a particular port?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall

I've hosted a simple Webserver on my Banana Pi. I can access him throgh `LAN`, but I cannot access him from outside the network. I've forwarded it with my router. I made a `NMAP` scan, and the result was that the port's state from outside was 'filtered'.
How to determine which process/programm is controlling/blocking a particular port?

Webserver:     Self-written, using Java's `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`
OS:            Raspbian, GNU/Linux
Forwarding:    From `19132` TCP to `19132` TCP
**[EDIT]**
Router: FRITZ!Box 6490
Iptables rules: none (sudo iptables -L)
Note: There is another **working** Website running on the same `LAN`, which is forwardet exactly like the one that is not working.

Comment: Are you trying to access it from a machine that's actually outside of your LAN, or are you trying to use the external name/IP from inside your LAN?

Comment: I have tried both, and both failed. I can only access it throgh the internal IP

Comment: Can you try traceroute command to understand where the packet is getting dropped? I am working on this now. Lets hope best.

Comment: Very likely the forwarding on your router doesn't work as intended, so you need to look at configuration of the router. Information needed is at least "what router", "what exactly did you configure".